# How to create a form using the static blocks in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have added the tab using catalog-Manage categories->Add subcategory and added the tab 'as quick service'

Added the form in below path

```
app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/quickservice/form.phtml
```

and added the cms page with the content

```
 <p>{{block type='core/template' name='quickservice' template="quickservice/form.phtml"}}</p>
```

But it is showing the empty page when I click on the tab.Please anyone can help me.

form.phtml

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="quickservice" method="post">
 <li class="fields">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="Servicetype" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Service Type') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select name="servicetype" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 150px;" />
                                    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
                                    <option value="Lab"><?php echo $this->__('Lab')?></option>
                                    <option value="Hospital"><?php echo $this->__('Hospital')?></option>
                                    <option value="Food"><?php echo $this->__('Food')?></option>
                                    <option value="Gym"><?php echo $this->__('Gym')?></option>
                                    <option value="Physio"><?php echo $this->__('Physio')?></option>
                                    <option value="Nurse"><?php echo $this->__('Nurse')?></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
            </div>
</li>
 </form>
```

Comment: remove this  <?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?> and check

Comment: No,It is not working

Comment: is this admin side

Comment: no,for frontend in admin i had created the subcategory and cms page .

Comment: is it displaying footer?

Comment: Which footer? can you explain please

Comment: if the php error then the page execution are stop i test this this don't have any problem only check you path of template are correct try to add this file in base/default/template/quickservice/form.phtml and then check

Comment: yes copied the file in the base/default/template/quickservice/form.phtml but it is showing same empty page.

Comment: refresh ur cache and see the changes

Comment: refreshed the cache and checked but it is showing the same

Comment: @ Qaisar Satti Please suggest me it is not displaying the from

Comment: check in page source the form are there?

Comment: in which page source?

Comment: name='quickservice'  change it and check..

Comment: No,Changed the name and checked but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you applied the latest security patch? If so you might need to add a permission for "core/template" under "System -> Permissions -> Blocks"

Comment: Ni,I have not applied the latest security patch

Comment: What version of Magento are you using? Which setting did you choose for "display mode" under "Display Settings" in the Category?

Comment: magento version is=1.8.1 and static block only under dispaly mode

Comment: Can you add some more text to the static block and see if that shows up (or look if the <p> Tags show up)?

Comment: I have added the image in the static block and checked it is displaying

Comment: Add the following code to the beginning of the method "_toHtml" in the file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php

`Mage::log($this->getTemplateFile(), null, 'template.txt');`

You also need to enable Logging under "System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Log Setting". This will create a logfile named "template.txt" under var/log